# Install maven to any linux system using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, maven, installation

Is there any possible way I can install maven on any of the linux machine using a bash script ?

Comment: You can write one which downloads it and add the bin folder to the path? Maybe I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to do and how your environment is setup? Does is really need to be generic or do you have like 2-3 different distributions you want to install in on? In the latter case I would prefer writing a script that determines the distribution and uses the respective package manger.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-ubuntu/), you can install Maven using sudo:

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

then, run

```
mvn -version
```

to check that it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install mvn with bash script, example below

```sh
mvn_version=${mvn_version:-3.8.5}
url="http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.apache.org/maven/maven-3/${mvn_version}/binaries/apache-maven-${mvn_version}-bin.tar.gz"
install_dir="/opt/maven"

mkdir ${install_dir}
curl -fsSL ${url} | tar zx --strip-components=1 -C ${install_dir}
cat << EOF > /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
#!/bin/sh
export MAVEN_HOME=${install_dir}
export M2_HOME=${install_dir}
export M2=${install_dir}/bin
export PATH=${install_dir}/bin:$PATH
EOF
source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh
echo maven installed to ${install_dir}
mvn --version
```

you need to add **source /etc/profile.d/maven.sh** to ~/.bash_profile or basrch